# Composer update / install in different OS

Tags: php, composer-php

I believe that development process and environment should be identical to production environment. For that reason I even use same EC2 instance image for dev / prod etc.

However lately I have stumbled upon a team that develops on one OS, runs composer update in that OS, and then just releases everything to production from those, by copying even the vendor files.

That would be equivalent to run `composer update` in one OS and running `composer install` in a different OS.

- My question is whether this will work ?
- The dependencies discovered and installed by composer are independent of OS or are they tied to OS and other dependencies installed, on which `composer update` is running ?

Comment: Can you share more details? Why should this not work? Apparently, if another team runs such a process, wouldn't they have seen problems if such would occur?

Comment: @NicoHaase The reason behind my doubts are mentioned in the second bullet point.

Comment: When I ask, if this will work, I think the process of using composer requires one to run update and install in dev and prod environments. If the dependencies are tied to OS, the process will break.

Now as for other teams seeing this problem is concerned, I believe uploading vendor folder is not a standard approach, so I did not think others would have found this problem.

Comment: Uploading the vendor folder from some kind of CI server to the production system is pretty common - I try to avoid installing Composer on any production system, as it does not belong there. Also, I don't think that there are a lot of packages which are OS dependent